# Windows Phone 8.1 Photo Capture does not work

Tags: .net, mobile, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

For 2 days I'm trying to capture Photos with my Lumia 930 Windows Phone.

I am using the following code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture captureManager;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        First.Click += async (sender, e) => await Initialize();
        Second.Click += async (sender, e) => await shutter();
    }

    private async Task Initialize()
    {
        captureManager = new MediaCapture();

        var devices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceClass.VideoCapture);

        List<Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation> _deviceList = new List<Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation>();
        for (var i = 0; i < devices.Count; i++)
        {
            _deviceList.Add(devices[i]);
        }

        MediaCaptureInitializationSettings _captureInitSettings = null;
        _captureInitSettings = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
        _captureInitSettings.AudioDeviceId = "";
        _captureInitSettings.VideoDeviceId = "";
        _captureInitSettings.StreamingCaptureMode = Windows.Media.Capture.StreamingCaptureMode.AudioAndVideo;
        _captureInitSettings.PhotoCaptureSource = Windows.Media.Capture.PhotoCaptureSource.Photo;

        if (_deviceList.Count > 0)
            _captureInitSettings.VideoDeviceId = _deviceList[0].Id;

        await captureManager.InitializeAsync(_captureInitSettings);
        //capturePreview.Source = captureManager;
        //await captureManager.StartPreviewAsync();
        await SetResolution();
    }

    public async Task SetResolution()
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<IMediaEncodingProperties> res;
        res = this.captureManager.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo);
        uint maxResolution = 0;
        int indexMaxResolution = 0;
        string s = "";

        if (res.Count >= 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < res.Count; i++)
            {
                VideoEncodingProperties vp = (VideoEncodingProperties)res[i];
                var frameRate = (vp.FrameRate.Numerator / vp.FrameRate.Denominator);


                s = i + ") " + vp.Subtype + ", ";
                s = s + vp.Width;
                s = s + " x " + vp.Height;
                s = s + " , Frame/s: " + frameRate;

                if (vp.Width > maxResolution && vp.Subtype.Equals("YUY2"))
                {
                    indexMaxResolution = i;
                    maxResolution = vp.Width;

                }
                if (true)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(s);
                }
                s = "";
            }

            //setting resolution
            await captureManager.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo, res[indexMaxResolution]);

            return;

        }
    }

    private async Task shutter()
    {
        ImageEncodingProperties imageProperties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
        var photoStorageFile = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("Photo.JPG", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        await captureManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imageProperties, photoStorageFile);

        return;
    }

}
```

You can find the solution here:

http://1drv.ms/1nFWoCF

When I choose
    `_captureInitSettings.PhotoCaptureSource = Windows.Media.Capture.PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview;`

I get a photo, but in a very crappy resolution / quality. When using Photo, what would make much more sense, I get a 2MB file, which sounds quite right, but the content is only black and a yellow line, like if the lense was closed.

The camera is definitely working with Nokia Camera or other apps, so it cannot be a hardware problem.

Comment: Did you go through the msdn sample? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn376408.aspx

Comment: Hi, no, cause I don't want to use the CameraUI, plus: "Note  The CameraCaptureUI control is not available on Windows Phone 8.1 devices". It is driving me crazy that Microsoft is not providing a single example how to take a still picture, only a video!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you've chosen the right API for your task.

Instead of what you're doing, you should probably use [CameraCaptureTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394006(v=vs.105).aspx) (if you want the standard camera UI + images saved in the library) or [PhotoCamera](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.devices.photocamera(v=vs.105).aspx) (if you want your own camera UI and/or you don't want the photos to be saved in the user's library).

And don't forget about the ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA capability in the manifest.

Comment: Hi, thank you, sorry, I should have made it more clear: I would like to develop it for 8.1, not 8.0. And looks like CameraCaptureTask is not existing anymore in 8.1 and was replaced by MediaCapture API.

Comment: The first line says: Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1

Comment: Hmm yeah but as Silverlight is dead, I don't really want to use it anymore. So it should be a plain Windows Phone 8.1 app.

Comment: I’ve been hearing ‘bout dead Silverlight since 2011. Regardless of what you think, currently there’s more APIs exposed to Silverlight then to that new Windows Store runtime: all APIs available to windows store apps can be accessed from SL 8.1, the opposite is not true.
If you still do not like Silverlight (or you will need to port your app to desktop Windows), go on debugging your media capture code — WP 8.1 store runtime is brand new, it’s basically version 1.0, that’s why the API is still missing important pieces.

Comment: Thank you, you were totally right. By using the PhotoCameraDevice and AudioVideoDevice Classes within a Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight app, I managed to create photos in much higher quality and it was even much easier than with MediaCapture.

Answer (score 0):

I now managed to take a Picture, by starting a preview first. It seems not to work without a preview :/